# How to make a list of dicts with nested dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I am not sure if thats what i really want but i want this structure basically,

```
-document
  -pattern_key
     -start_position
     -end_position
```

right now i have this

```
dictionary[document] = {"pattern_key":key, "startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}
```

but i want to nest startPos, endPos under pattern key

Also how can i update this, to add a new entry of pattern_key, startPos, endPos, under same document?

Answer (score 0):

with this you can updates values of the keys

```
for x in dict.keys():
     if 'pattern_key' in x:
          dict[x]= 'new value'
     if 'endPost'...
     .....

print dict
>>> should have new values
```

for add new entrys:

```
old = {}
old['keyxD'] = [9999]
new = {}
new['newnewnew'] = ['supernewvalue']
new.update(old)
print new
>>>{'newnewnew': ['supernewvalue'], 'keyxD': [9999]}
```

Comment: hmm i do not want to replace with new values, i want to add new entry to existing key.

Comment: ahhhhh i understand, wait sure i can help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly want, but you can try this:

```
document = {'pattern_key' : {}}
```

This created an object `document` which is a dictionary, where the key is a string (pattern_key) and the value is another dictionary. Now, to add new entries to the value of the dictionary (which is another dictionary) you just add your values:

```
document['pattern_key']['start_position'] = 1
document['pattern_key']['end_position'] = 10
```

Afterwards, you can enter either case with `document['pattern_key']['start_position'] = 2` and this will change the start position to 2.

Hope this helps